# grails and flash movie

Tags: flash, grails, gsp

Is it possibe to insert into GSP simple flash movie?

I tried this way:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="${resource(dir:'flash',file:'movie.swf')}" width="400" height="400">
            <param name="movie" value="${resource(dir:'flash',file:'movie.swf')}" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="feed=${resource(dir:'flash',file:'movie.xml')}" />
            <p>This widget requires Flash Player 9 or better</p>
        </object>
```

It seems that movie is loaded but .xml and pictures are not...

UPD
tried to use flash-plugin 1.3.0 - the same result

```
<g:flashPlayer id="test"
                       varFile="${resource(dir: 'flash', file: 'movie.swf')}" paramAllowScriptAccess="always" flashvars="feed=${resource(dir:'flash',file:'movie.xml')}"/>
```

Comment: Did you check the html code generated by grails to see if it was pointing to the correct location.

Comment: location is correct, I am not sure about <param name="flashvars" value="feed=${resource(dir:'flash',file:'movie.xml')}"

Answer (score 1):

Having not used grails before, I'm not sure what's wrong with your syntax, but I can recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your swf rather than the standard object/embed tags. There's a write up about using swfobject with grails here: http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/grails-seo-swfobject-and-flex-progressive-enhancement/.

I find it's a bit easier to debug your embed using swfobject, and it is also the recommended method for standards compliant flash embeds.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround with iframe